# tkinter - When resizing color image, it shows up in red scale only

Tags: python, user-interface, opencv, tkinter

I have the following piece of code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2
import os
import glob
import numpy as np


image_path = ""
image_list = []
class Proj:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        #GUI height and width
        w = 1250 
        h = 600

        # open folder manager to select image folder
        image_path =  filedialog.askdirectory()

        master.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (w ,h ,0,0))
        master.resizable(True,True)

        #read in images from folder
        self.read_images(master, image_path)
        #cv2.imshow('image',cv2.imread(image_list[0], 1))
        self.img = cv2.imread(image_list[0])

        self.img = Image.fromarray(np.array(self.img).copy())
        self.img.thumbnail((w//2, w//2+10))
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)


        image_frame = Frame(master)
        image_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 5)
        left_panel = Canvas(image_frame, width=w//2, height=h-70)
        left_panel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)      
        imgA_handler = left_panel.create_image((0,0), image = self.img, anchor="nw")

        right_panel = Canvas(image_frame, width=w//2, height=h-70)
        right_panel.grid(row=0, column=5, columnspan=4)

    def read_images(self, master, path):
        images = path + '/*.tif'
        for img in glob.glob(images): #will only read in tif images
            image_list.append(img)

root = Tk()     
example = Proj(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I am reading in color **.tif** images and then trying to display them in the `left_panel.` However, when I go to do that, it **shows the normal color image only in red scale** even *though I never extracted just the red signal*. I am completely unable to diagnose the issue. How do I fix this issue?

Ultimately, what I want to do is display two images on this GUI. An original image on the left and a modified image on the right. Currently my gui layout is set up as I've coded above. However, if you think there is an easier way to do this, then I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: The code you have provided will not work as it is incomplete. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can actually test your code.

Comment: I've attached just the relevant parts of the code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because opencv uses BGR instead of RGB. When you are using this line: `self.img = Image.fromarray(np.array(self.img).copy())` Blue and Red colors are being swapped. Just before you use the above code, convert the BGR to RGB in opencv and you should be good to go.

```
self.img = cv2.cvtColor(self.img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using opencv. Why don't you use the opencv command to resize.
     It is very simple and works pretty well.

Take a look at this page:

[OpenCV Resize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation))

This is an example to make a image 50% smaller, or instead of the fx and fy, you can put the exact size you want.

```
thumbnail = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question. The question is why the color changes to red.

Comment: When I tried this ( I commented out my previous `thumbnail` command) and used `resize`, it said src is neither numpy array or scalar. I tried just calling this function right after imread and that just printed a bunch of matrices and said doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you try something like:

`import cv2`

`image = cv2.imread("original.jpg")`

`thumbnail = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)`

`cv2.imwrite("resized.jpg", thumbnail)`

That works for me, or post your modified code.